# Solving the heat equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations

> Solve the heat equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions:
>   $$\begin{cases}
> u_t = ku_{xx} \ \ \text{for} \ \ 0 < x < l,\\
> u(0,t) = u(l,t) = 0 \\
> u(x,0) = x^2 
> \end{cases}$$
>   Your final answer should remain in series form. You can use, without proof, that, for $0 < x < l$, 
>   $$x^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\right) \ \ \text{where} \ \ A_n = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}2}{n\pi} + \frac{4}{n^3 \pi ^3}((-1)^{n+1} - 1)$$

Attempted solution - We can solve this with separation of variables 
$$u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$$ 
This PDE yields 
$$X(x)T'(t) = k X^{\prime \prime}T(t)$$ 
Rearranging algebraically we have 
$$\frac{X^{\prime\prime}(x)}{X(x)} = \frac{T'(t)}{k T(t)} = -\lambda$$

where $\lambda$ is some constant. Rearranging again we get 
$$X^{\prime \prime} + \lambda X = 0 \ \ \text{and} \ \ T' + k\lambda T = 0$$
Now considering the boundary conditions we get the eigenvalue and eigenfunctions which are denoted 
$$\lambda_n = \left(\frac{n\pi}{l}\right)^2, \ \ n = 0,1,2,\ldots$$
and 
$$X_n(x) = \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l} \right)$$
The general solution is given by 
$$u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \exp\left(-k (n\pi/l)^2t \right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x }{l}\right)$$
To find $A_n$ we have 
\begin{align*}
A_n &= \frac{2}{l}\int_{0}^{l}\phi(x)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\right)dx\\
&= \frac{2}{l}\int_{0}^{l}x^2 \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l} \right)dx\\
&= \vdots\\
&= \frac{2 l^2((2 - n^2 \pi^2)\cos(n\pi) + 2 n \pi \sin(n\pi) - 2}{n^3 \pi^3}
\end{align*}
Therefore we have $$u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2 l^2((2 - n^2 \pi^2)\cos(n\pi) + 2 n \pi \sin(n\pi) - 2}{n^3 \pi^3}\exp\left(-k (n\pi/l)^2t \right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x }{l}\right)$$

I skipped over some details since we already solved this in general for the Dirichlet boundary condition with an arbitrary function so I just included what I think would be a sufficient enough solution. I am not sure if this is complete or correct and where to go from here. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't really need to compute the integral of $x^2 \sin (\frac{n \pi x}{L})$. You could of plugged in the series expansion of $x^2$, exchange sum and integral and lastly note the orthogonality of $\sin (\frac{n \pi x}{L})$ and $ \sin (\frac{k \pi x}{L})$ if $n \neq k$.

Comment: Something looks strange in your after "Rearranging algebraically we have" step.

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk I sort of follow what you mean, but where do I go from where I left off?

Comment: You are done! "Your final answer should remain in series form" which you now have. You do seem to be missing a square in the exponent - it should be $\exp ( -k \lambda t)$.

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk Huh, perhaps its just me then but I feel like this problem was rather pointless since we already did this but with instead of $x^2$ its just $\phi(x)$

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk Is my solution correct?

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 it seems fine now yes.